# average of numbers enter in textbox

Tags: javascript

Can somebody help me to calculate the average of numbers that was entered by a user in textbox. it's up to the user to add more textbox to enter new number and after display the average in a new textbox. For instance the user enter 67, 87, 45 in 3 textbox automatically the average 66.33 pop up in a new textbox. If he wants he can add new texbox to keep entering numbers.
Thank you so much

i post my codes working properly i happen to calculate only the sum of texbox i miss the average now

```
<script>

Function send() {
val1 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_2.value);
if (isNaN(val1) == true ) val1=0;
val2 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_3.value);
if (isNaN(val2) == true ) val2=0;
val3 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_4.value);
if (isNaN(val3) == true ) val3=0;
val4 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_5.value);
if (isNaN(val4) == true ) val4=0;


function switchInfoPerso()
{
divInfo = document.getElementById('divacacher');
if (divInfo.style.display == 'none')
divInfo.style.display = 'block';
else
divInfo.style.display = 'none';
}
function switchInfoPerso1()
{
divInfo = document.getElementById('divacacher1');
if (divInfo.style.display == 'none')
divInfo.style.display = 'block';
else
divInfo.style.display = 'none';
}

function switchInfoPerso2()
{
divInfo = document.getElementById('divacacher2');
if (divInfo.style.display == 'none')
divInfo.style.display = 'block';
else
divInfo.style.display = 'none';
}

function switchInfoPerso3()
{
divInfo = document.getElementById('divacacher3');
if (divInfo.style.display == 'none')
divInfo.style.display = 'block';
else
divInfo.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<table>
<tr><td> 
<label>Audit Result</label> 
</td> 
<td> </br>
<label>#1</label> <input type="text" name="valeur_2" id="valeur_2"      
onchange="send()" size="10" /> <b>%</b> </br></br>
<a href="javascript: switchInfoPerso();" style="color:black">Show #2</a>
<div id="divacacher" style="display: none;"> 
<label>#2</label> <input type="text" name="valeur_3" id="valeur_3"    
onchange="send()"  size="10"/> <b>%</b> </br></br>

<a href="javascript: switchInfoPerso1();" style="color:black">Show #3</a>
<div id="divacacher1" style="display: none;"> 
<label>#3</label> <input type="text" name="valeur_4" id="valeur_4"   
onchange="send()" size="10"/><b>%</b>  </br></br>

<a href="javascript: switchInfoPerso2();" style="color:black">Show #4</a>
<div id="divacacher2" style="display: none;"> 
<label>#4</label> <input type="text" name="valeur_5" id="valeur_5"  
onchange="send()" size="10"/><b>%</b>  </br></br>

<a href="javascript: switchInfoPerso3();" style="color:black">Show #5</a>
<div id="divacacher3" style="display: none;"> 
<label>#5</label> <input type="text" name="valeur_6" id="valeur_6"   
onchange="send()" size="10"/><b>%</b>  </br></br></tr>
<tr><td> 
<label>Total audit result</label> 
</td> 
<td> 
<input type="text"  name="total" id="total" /></td></tr> 
<tr><td> 
<label>Audit average</label> 
</td> 
<td> 
<input type="text"  name="average" id="average" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

I confess that your codes are simpler and more professional that mine, however i need time to understand them and apply them to my application. That's why i would like to ask you to add the average function which apply to my codes posted, it will be easier for me to solve my issue meanwhile i focus on your codes to learn and understand them.THe total audit result works, i miss the audit average. thanks

Comment: For this to be a proper SO question, you need to try this on your own. If you get stuck and have some code or HTML to show that has a problem with it, then come back and ask a question about the specific issue you're having

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following, depending on your needs:

Bind the function to recalculate the number to the `document`, adding a selector for the text inputs you want to calculate. If you bind the function to the input class directly, dynamically created inputs won't execute the function.

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input.calcme", function () {
    recalc();
});
```

calculate the values by dividing the sum by the number of members:

```
function recalc() {
    var sum = 0;
    var nums = 0;
    $(".calcme").each(function () {
        nums++;
        sum += 1 * $(this).val();   // multiply by one to enforce numeric interpretation
    });
    $("#result").val(sum / nums);
}
```

Append a new input on button click:

```
function addmore() {
    $("#inputs").append('<input type="text" class="calcme" value="0" />');
    recalc();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input type="text" class="calcme" />
</div>
<button id="addmode" onclick="addmore()">+</button>
<input readonly="readonly" id="result" />
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/ovhb80jg/

Comment: Thank you so much for your codes, but i'm stuck to store the input values in variable to send them after in a table using sql and php. It's more simple than my codes but this issue is showing for me. If i could calculate the average by using the same methode i used for my codes?

Comment: thanks for your codes but i don't know how to sent the values in the textbox in a msql table using php and sql

Comment: When do you want to store the values? Each time something changes or upon clicking a submit button?
Either way, you might use a form, using a .php script handling the SQL as the `action` target. Please refer to manuals explaining HTML forms and PDO and SQL, OR show us your attempts so far.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    addInput(false);

    $("#av").on("click", ".addNumber", function () {
        addInput(true);
    });

    $("#av .inputs").on("keydown", "input", function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == '9' && !(e.shiftKey) && $(this).parent("p").next("p").length === 0) addInput(true);
    });

    $("#av").on("click", ".removeInput", function () {
        $(this).parent("p").remove();
    });

    function addInput(removable) {
        var input = "";
        if (!removable) {
            input = "<p><input type='text' maxlength='30' placeholder='Number'/></p>";
        } else {
            input = "<p><input type='text' maxlength='30' placeholder='Number'/><input type='button' class='removeInput' value='Remove' tabindex='-1'/></p>";
        }
        $(input).appendTo("#av .inputs");
    }

    $("#av .inputs").on("keyup", "input", function () {
        var length = $("#av .inputs").children("p").length;
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var val = $("#av .inputs").find("p:eq(" + i + ")").find("input").val();
            $("#av .inputs").find("p:eq(" + i + ")").find("input[type='text']").val(val.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
            val = $("#av .inputs").find("p:eq(" + i + ")").find("input[type='text']").val();
            total += parseInt(val, 10);
        }
        var result = total / length;
        if (result % 1 !== 0) result = result.toFixed(3); //Edit this if you want decimal places
        $("#av .result").val(result);
    });
});
```

```css
input[type="text"], input[type="number"] {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -web-kit-border-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="number"]:focus {
    border: 1px solid #1CCDE8;
    outline: none;
}
input[type="submit"]:not(.removeInput), input[type="button"]:not(.removeInput) {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -web-kit-border-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px;
    outline: none;
}
input[type="submit"].removeInput, input[type="button"].removeInput {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #999;
}
input[type="submit"]:not(.removeInput):hover, input[type="button"]:not(.removeInput):hover {
    background-color: #1CCDE8;
    color: white;
}
form p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="av">
    <input class="addNumber" type="button" value="Add Number" />
    <div class="inputs"></div>
    <input class="result" type="text" disabled />
</form>
```

You can add and remove inputs, you can edit the amount of decimal values you want to include (if a number is not a whole number, see comments in the jquery script), you can tab to add another input field, if you want you can add a default value.

I haven't cleaned the code up yet, when/if I do, I will edit my post accordingly.

In order to get to the value to a database (as your comment on another answer shows your intent to be), you need to give the input with a class of result (in my script above) a name (say `name='result'`) and the access that variable through your PHP script (i.e. Using the POST method: `$_POST['result'];`). Make sure you sanitize the result before you input it into the database too!